# es6-promise: promisify'ing httpntlm module

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await, es6-promise

I wanted to make the `httpntlm` module to return a promise, its implemented with callbacks.

Here is a working version with callbacks:

```
httpntlm.get({
  url,
  username: 'username',
  password: 'banana'
}, 
function (err, resx){
  if(err) console.log(err);
  else {
    console.log(resx.headers);
    console.log(resx.body);
  }
});
```

Here is how i am trying to make it to return a promise:

```
promisify(httpntlm.post(config, (error, response) => {
  if (error) return errro
  return response
}))
.then(res => console.log(res))
.catch(err => console.log(err))
```

But the promisify version returns error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "original" argument must be of type Function. Received type undefined

What i am missing? Thanks

Comment: Try removing return inside arrow function. and write like this 

promisify(httpntlm.post(config, (error, response) => {
  if (error)  errro
   response
}))

Answer (score 9):

This is what the [docs say to `util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original):

> `util.promisify(original)`
>
> - original `<Function>`
> - Returns: `<Function>`

As the error message states

> The "original" argument must be of type Function, Received type undefined

What you did:

```
promisify(httpntlm.post(config, (error, response) => {
  if (error) return error
  return response
}))
```

You already *called* the function. And `httpntlm.post` being an asynchronous function, it returns nothing.

You should have *passed* the function:

```
var httpntlmPostAsync =  promisify(httpntlm.post);

// if `post` depends on `this`
var httpntlmPostAsync =  promisify(httpntlm.post.bind(httpntlm));
```

That's all.

In other words, `promisify` does not call a function for you, or apply any magic to a running function call. It *makes a new function* that behaves differently.

```
httpntlmPostAsync({
  url: 'url',
  username: 'username',
  password: 'banana'
})
.then(res => console.log(res))
.catch(err => console.log(err))
```

or, if you like that better:

```
async function foo() {
  try {
    var res = await httpntlmPostAsync({
      url: 'url',
      username: 'username',
      password: 'banana'
    });
    console.log(res);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

---

To promisify multiple functions, you can use something like this:

```
['get', 'post', 'etc'].forEach(method => 
    httpntlm[method + 'Async'] = promisify(httpntlm[method].bind(httpntlm))
);
```

After that, `httpntlm.getAsync`, `httpntlm.postAsync`, etc are available.

Comment: Nice article about this is [here](https://stackabuse.com/converting-callbacks-to-promises-in-node-js/)